# Mysql Stored Procedure Equation Step By Step for newbie?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

Hello I'm a newbie in MySQL and need step by step help for this case

I have database name `p_data`
which has different tables with relationship by `index` `unique` value

first table name is `f_table`

```
 -----------------
 |    f_table    |
 -----------------
 |      AV2      |
 |               |
 -----------------
```

second table is `s_table`

```
 -----------------
 |    s_table    |
 -----------------
 |      AV3      |
 |               |
 ----------------
```

I want make each `AV3` Value for each data entry equal this formula like Excel

```
 AV3 =

 =IF(AND(AV2>=1, AV2<40), 0, IF(AND(AV2>=40, AV2<=49), 18, 
  IF(AND(AV2>=50, AV2<=59), 36, IF(AND(AV2>=60, AV2<=69), 55, 
  IF(AND(AV2>=70, AV2<=79), 73,IF(AND(AV2>=80),91,""))))))
```

**example**

```
 if AV2 >= 1 or < 40 
 So AV3 = 0

 if AV2 >= 40 or =< 49 
 So AV3 = 18

 and So on ...
```

How to run MySQL to deal with each data entry and run the value according to the first equation example and add it automatically from first table to second table with each data entry?

Comment: Quoting how you do it in excel isn't all that helpful - it's better that the question explains your requirement in plain english.

Comment: i already did example if AV2 >= 1 or < 40 So AV3 = 0

Answer (score 1):

Assuming both `p_table` and `s_table` have a field `id` which has the same value for corresponding entries,  you could do this:

```
UPDATE s_table s
JOIN p_table p ON s.id=p.id
SET s.AV3 = CASE 
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 1 AND  39 THEN 0
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 40 AND  49 THEN 18
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 50 AND  59 THEN 36
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 60 AND  69 THEN 55
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 70 AND  79 THEN 73
    WHEN p.AV2 >= 80 THEN 91
    ELSE NULL
    END
```

**Edit** As @GordonLinoff points out, it's probably better to have the `ELSE` clause return `NULL` instead of `''` to be consistent with an integer data type.

Comment: DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE cal_me
BEGIN
UPDATE s_table s
JOIN p_table p ON s.id=p.id
SET s.AV3 = CASE 
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 1 AND  39 THEN 0
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 40 AND  49 THEN 18
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 50 AND  59 THEN 36
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 60 AND  69 THEN 55
    WHEN p.AV2 BETWEEN 70 AND  79 THEN 73
    WHEN p.AV2 >= 80 THEN 91
    ELSE   
END //
DELIMITER ;

Comment: MySQL said: Documentation
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN
UPDATE s_table s
JOIN p_table p ON s.id=p.id
SET s.AV3 = CASE
    WHE' at line 2

Comment: wow working perfect ,,, how can i make run automatic in this the database

Comment: To make it run automatically you would need to set up an insert trigger. Take a look at the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html), give it a try and if you can't make it work, it would be a good new question to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tweak on Nick's answer:

```
UPDATE s_table s JOIN
       p_table p
       ON s.id = p.id
    SET s.AV3 = (CASE WHEN p.AV2 < 40 AND p.AV2 >= 0 THEN 0
                      WHEN p.AV2 < 50 THEN 18
                      WHEN p.AV2 < 60 THEN 36
                      WHEN p.AV2 < 70 THEN 55
                      WHEN p.AV2 < 80 THEN 73
                      WHEN p.AV2 >= 80 THEN 91
                      ELSE NULL
                 END);
```

The changes are:

- Simplification to the `CASE` expression, recognizing that the values are implemented in order.
- Fixing the `ELSE` clause to use `NULL`, so the types are consistent.

Comment: thanks Gordon but output shows #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '> 0 THEN 0
                      WHEN p.AV2 < 50 THEN 18
                     ' at line 4

Comment: I wouldn't have objected to you editing my answer. The point about NULL is a good one; I simply copied the value from OPs post without really thinking about it.

Comment: @Nick . . . It seemed like a substantial change.  I upvoted your answer.

Comment: Allow me to return the favour.